# GeoServer WMS issues

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, geoexplorer

My WMS on a local test server was working fine with GeoExplorer but suddenly stopped working and now I don't get the LocalServer in the datasources list. I have tried reboot/restart.

I tried adding it (`http://localhost:8081/geoserver/ccc_beta/wms`) manually but that doesn't work.

I can however view the data in OpenLayers without any issues.

However Geoxplorer and other software access to WMS doesn't work.

In QGIS -add WMS I get

```
Could not understand the response.  The WMS provider said:
Could not get WMS capabilities: error occurred while parsing element at line 5086 column 11
This is probably due to an incorrect WMS Server URL.
Response was:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WMS_Capabilities version="1.3.0" updateSequence="1019" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://localhost:8081/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd">
  <Service>
    <Name>WMS</Name>
    <Title>GeoServer Web Map Service</Title>
```

I also cleared all my stores/cache etc.

Version2.2-SNAPSHOT
Git Revisionadbea2ddf643dce951945d291174a4714fdd801

==== UPDATE

I put the data on to a Linux install and it was all working fine till now when I restarted the machine and get the same error only in Geoexplorer (can't find local data) but everything works fine in OpenLayers view. The log is

```
2013-07-24 09:30:58,239 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.text/html' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,239 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/xml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,241 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to reproject layer worldto spherical mercator
2013-07-24 09:30:58,241 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.image/png; mode=8bit' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,242 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/vnd.google-earth.kmz' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,242 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.text/html' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,242 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/xml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,244 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to reproject layer pop_heatmapto spherical mercator
2013-07-24 09:30:58,244 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.image/png; mode=8bit' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,244 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/vnd.google-earth.kmz' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,244 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.text/html' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,244 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/xml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,246 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to reproject layer volcano_clusterto spherical mercator
2013-07-24 09:30:58,246 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.image/png; mode=8bit' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,246 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/vnd.google-earth.kmz' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,247 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.text/html' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:30:58,247 INFO [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/xml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.OpenGeoMapPreviewPage]
2013-07-24 09:31:26,874 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2013-07-24 09:31:26,922 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
```

Comment: One of your GeoServer layers is broken, check the log file for more details

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I had your problem all week. I feel like geoserver is too sensitive to changes that really shouldn't impact it.

Check any styles you have edited, as sometime when in geoexplorer you accidentally overwrite styles. I had accidentally overwritten the point layer, I realised at the time, and thought I had fixed it. If you have made SLD changes, simply google SLD Point layer for example, and get the full code and replace the style.

I originally thought it was down to the data source / layer, but after 3 hours of trial and error the fix was restoring the point SLD I had created yesterday. Funny thing is it worked fine yesterday until I turned it off, so maybe a caching error giving me false hope

Comment: Now I broke my linux install as well. See the updated question for the log info. I am going to just try a reinstall.

Comment: @GeorgeC Hmm im not to sure about that one. I also had to create a new Linux server after I totally messed up mu installation. I would make a note of any key changes you do to your GIS, layers, styles, settings, that way you have an idea of what to back track on.